# Am I exposed to high levels of radiation at my job?

Tags: antenna, wireless, electromagnetism, wifi, radiation

I made this post because I have a safety concern about my job as medical device tester. I was reading the user manual of the equipment I work with and found the next warning:

“Per FCC regulations, maintain a distance of at least 7.8 inches/20 cm between the Radio Card on the unit and a human body”

I work with 6 units, which each one has a small wireless antenna, but I also have coworkers that work with the same number of units, resulting in 36 units in total.

My question is if there is any risk for being exposed to the radiation of these equipment, by risk I mean getting cancer.

Notes:
The wireless of the units are enabled, but we are not connecting the devices to computers, we are testing other functionalities.

The units operates on the following frequencies with a maximum radiated power of 100 mW:

• 802.11a: 5 GHz band, up to 54 Mbps physical RF specification.

• 802.11b: 2.4 GHz band, up to 11 Mbps physical RF specification.

• 802.11g: 2.4 GHz band, up to 54 Mbps physical RF specification.

• 802.11n: 5 GHz or 2.4 GHz band, up to 72 Mbps physical RF specification.

Comment: Speak with the people whose manual you read.

Comment: The short answer is no, but what country are you in?

Comment: You will have to make your own guesses about this. In general, we don't know enough to draw bright lines for you. And the desire by public non-health regulatory agencies in the US to protect public health is mostly driven by corporate interests. The NIH says 7g of Tylenol in a day is sufficient to cause "serious liver damage." But for decades 4g per day was the **recommended** daily usage limit. And 2g was considering the minimum effective dose.  You'll have to work out your own comfort level.

Comment: I live in California, USA. I was reading that a modern cellphone radiates around 1.6 Watts/ Kg. Not sure If my conclusion is right, but all these 36 devices would be equal to 4 smartphones.

Comment: Radiation density goes down by squared value of distance. So, you cannot simply add nominal values of transmit power of those devices.

Comment: @Kaizen90 That's not a radiation level, that's explosure or absorbtion level.

Comment: @Jonk - comments , not disagreement: - The Tylenol liver damage dose and recommended max does are both "correct. NZ max limit/day is 4g. Toxic starts at 8g/day. (8=7 :-) ).Tylenol/Paracetamol has the lowest toxic:max therapeutic ratio of any over the counter drug. It is extremely dangerous when used wrongly (= 2 x max daily does) and "safe enough" at 1/2 that dose. I have had numerous people 'get upset with me' over the years for pointing this out. | A UK university (OXford I think) keeps an international register of minimum fatal doses of various drugs. For Tylenol the dose was 4g/day.  ...

Comment: @Jonk Being female & having liver issues (she was) makes it more dangerous. Alcohol use makes it worse again. I sometimes take 1 x 500 mg Tylenol tablet. A pharmacist noted that this was "below the therapeutic dose level". For me at least it certainly isn't. As a "NSAID" Tylenol joins the others for liver damage, reducing fracture healing and possibly cardiac effects. An interesting world we live in. | I find Codeine useful when needed. Doctors are understandably nervous about prescribing it due to massive misuse. [I had a broken clavicle some months back. T & C both had their place].

Comment: @Kaizen90 Hazard level is almost certainly minimal. A vast number of studies over many decades have proven AND disproven links between moderate level EM radiation from power lines, cell sites, cellphones, house wiring and more. What this strongly suggests is that IF there are effects then they are "in the noise" and we are as likely or more likely or much more likely to be affected by eg pollution, food, alcohol, travelling by car, ... or failing to look properly when stepping into a roadway. Take sensible precautions (don't stand close when there is no need to), ... BUT DO NOT WORRY about it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I didn't mention it, but in the US there are (or were when I called them) three research groups doing studies on acetaminophen and humans. I called the lead researcher at each location (Washington DC, Dallas, and Denver) and got an education about the primary pathway and the three common tertiary pathways in the liver. (I didn't let any of them know I was speaking to the others.) They all said the same thing: a human liver can process about 1g per day. No more without the tertiary (dangerous) pathways getting involved. None of them considered 4g even slightly close to safe.

Comment: @jonk Thanks for that information. Are you able to provide a link to the research groups (off or on line). I have for decades sought to highlight the small ratio between Paracetamol's highly dangerous and highly useful dose rates. It's "interesting" that the dangers are well known by the medical profession but that no weight related dosages are ever suggested. 1g is the standard dose for people of any weight, male or female, and minimal if any mention is made of the extra hazard of higher alcohol consumption.  email address in my profile if needed.

Comment: My post was put on hold for off topic, what can I do to fit the rules?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon are 36 units considered moderate radiation?

Comment: @Kaizen90 36 x 100 mW = 3.6W. Yes, that's "moderate". The effective power, if you believe the standard that caused the 200mm limit to be set is Ptot = square_root(summation(200/dn_mm)squared) x 100 mW. ) Where dn is the distance from you to unit n. Mean separation to not exceed the level from one unit is then sqrt(Ptot/100 mW) x 200mm. | I would happily work in that environment taking sensible precautions - eg try to avoid sucking the aerial of a transmitting unit. Or touching it - but touching it is probably far far safer than crossing the average road. ...

Comment: ..., do not walk with your shoelaces untied, be extra careful when walking through a door that opens both ways, try to avoid eating toast etc that has been charred (possibly carconogenic), don't smoke, don't vape, don't inghest pot via any apthway, ...  **IMPORTANT** I am NOT making fun of this subject - it's PROBABLY safer than many other daily activities. Some people disagree. Nobody is utterly certain. Take a few easy and obvious sensible precautions, don't worry, live life. It is VERY likely that it causes no problems and odds are the burnt toast or sunburn or ... is worse for you.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people worry about health effects of electromagnetic radiation, and you'll find a lot of scaremongering misinformation on the web, but it is generally agreed by doctors and scientists that the electromagnetic radiation from WiFi equipment is extremely unlikely to cause any remotely significant risk of cancers. The [World Health Organization says](https://www.who.int/peh-emf/about/WhatisEMF/en/index1.html):

> Despite many studies, the evidence for any effect remains highly
>   controversial. However, it is clear that if electromagnetic fields do
>   have an effect on cancer, then any increase in risk will be extremely
>   small. The results to date contain many inconsistencies, but no large
>   increases in risk have been found for any cancer in children or
>   adults.
>
> A number of epidemiological studies suggest small increases in risk of
>   childhood leukemia with exposure to low frequency magnetic fields in
>   the home. However, scientists have not generally concluded that these
>   results indicate a cause-effect relation between exposure to the
>   fields and disease (as opposed to artifacts in the study or effects
>   unrelated to field exposure). In part, this conclusion has been
>   reached because animal and laboratory studies fail to demonstrate any
>   reproducible effects that are consistent with the hypothesis that
>   fields cause or promote cancer. Large-scale studies are currently
>   underway in several countries and may help resolve these issues.

In a comment on your question you said that *I was reading that a modern cellphone radiates around 1.6 Watts/ Kg*. That's a measure of [specific absorption rate](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/specific-absorption-rate-sar-cell-phones-what-it-means-you) which is not the same thing as the radiated power of your WiFi devices.

In general if you have a concern about the safety of your workplace, your first step should be to find out what the law where you are says and whether your company is complying with it. For example if you were in the UK there would need to be a risk assessment for the task you were doing, documenting what hazards had been identified and what measures needed taking to reduce them. If you aren't happy with the process or your company's compliance with it then you would need to look at what options you have for resolving that with your employer, either internally (using company procedures) or externally (using the law).

Comment: What is the difference between the radiation generated by a cellphone and a wireless device?

Answer (score 0):

Are you within 20cm of the radios?

Those warnings are generally in place as a defense against lawsuits, meaning if you did get sick they would say you ignored the warnings and so it isn't their fault.

That doesn't mean that being within 20cm is dangerous, it just means they think if it *was* dangerous that being outside 20cm might be safe(er).

How do they come up with the number? Who knows, they may have actual research on rodents or something or they might just do some math and think that sounds like a good number. Obviously they can't pick an unreasonable distance or no one could use the device within the safety guidelines.

FFC type regulations often don't mean much, unless you want to sue someone or not be sued yourself. In the past they have been horribly wrong and you have lots of cases of things with no evidence of being dangerous getting banned due to pressure from lobby groups.

There are some difficulties with this area. Firstly it's practically impossible to do a controlled study on humans, since all of us are subject to a bunch of RF radiation. Where are you going to get your control group that doesn't have a cell phone or WiFi?

Unless there is new research I'm unaware of, there has previously been no known biological interaction with RF and human tissue that could cause the sort of cell damage required to cause cancer. This is true of all non-ionizing radiation, there simply is no known method for it to cause us harm in that way.

It can certainly heat you up to the point you would burn if there was enough power, so I wouldn't recommending standing in the path of a really high power transmitter up close.

Of course not knowing of a way it can be harmful doesn't mean it's perfectly safe either. I can really only suggest you read some proper peer reviewed studies on the effects of RF and make your decisions based on that. Keep up with the latest research so you know if anyone does find some risk factors you need to think about.

There is a **lot** of scare mongering out there, but you can usually identify it because they want to sell you something.

Also make sure your work place is following any relevant safety guidelines.

I should also say there are studies that show a statistical link between RF exposure and cancers. They aren't great studies because they don't really eliminate other environmental factors well. One I recall was of military radar operators from several different countries where they all had statistically significant increases in rates for certain cancers compared with other personnel and the general public. The other I remember was done on people diagnosed with certain head tumors and studied their mobile phone usage, which found most of the patients had high levels of mobile usage.

So there has been some statistical evidence, even if the mechanism is unknown. But like I said, these studies don't really control for other factors. For example high powered radar equipment is constructed with a bunch of fairly toxic materials, how much exposure did the operators have to these? The study did not investigate that.

[Mobile Phone Study](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/bmri/2017/9218486/)

[Radar Operator Study](http://electromagneticsafeplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Radiofrequency-radiation-related-cancer-and-causation-in-the-military-setting.pdf)

Accuse me of scare mongering if you want, but it's not fair to say there hasn't been evidence of correlation. Which is not causation, obviously.

Comment: Scare monger much yourself?  The studies you mention towards the end are the fringe, and have not been replicated.  You are remembering what some scare mongering reporter said, and repeating it.  Look up those studies.  I think you'll find there is very little truth to them.

Comment: No I've read the papers. I can find and link them if you really want.